# How to stop Windows Server Standard from booting me while remoted in?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server

I'm using Remote Desktop connection to connect to a Windows Server box, on which I am an admit. If I'm idle for a few minutes, it locks me out (killing file transfers, which is a problem), and a few minutes after that, it severs my connection. Where can I find the settings that govern these things to stop that from happening? I want it to let me stay connected, regardless if I'm idle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look in the `sessions` tab in the properties of the windows account you are using. There are `idle session limit` and `active session limit` properties you can change.

You can also do it via GP
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758177%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I also found this: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1259649&page=1